# Use mqtt message data in program not only in on_message function (paho mqtt python)

Tags: python, function, mqtt, paho

I have a little python script which connects, subscribes, publish and disconnects to a mqtt broker. Everything is fine, but I only can use the received data in the on_message function.

first the actual code:

```
import time
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\user\\Python\\pyproj\\project1\\Lib\\site-packages\\paho_mqtt-1.6.1-py3.10.egg')
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

userdata = "Leer"
client_name = "Pythonscript"
broker_address="000.000.000.000"
port = 1234
topic = "topic to publish"
subtopic = "topic to recieve"
mqtt1 = ''

def on_log(client, userdata, level, buf):
    print(" client: ",client)
    print(" userdata: ",userdata)
    print(" level: ",level)
    print(" buf: ",buf)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    if rc==0:
        #print("connected OK ")
        #print("Subscribing to topic ",subtopic)
        client.subscribe(subtopic)
    else:
        print("Bad Connection Returned code=",rc)
    
        
def on_message(client,userdata,msg):
    topic=msg.topic
    m_decode=str(msg.payload.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
    global mqtt1
    mqtt1 = m_decode
    print("message recieved:",m_decode)
    print("message in mqtt1:",mqtt1)
    return m_decode
    
def on_disconnect(client, userdata, flags, rc=0):
    print("Disconnected result code "+str(rc))

print("creating new instance ",client_name)
client = mqtt.Client(client_name)

client.on_connect=on_connect
client.on_disconnect=on_disconnect
#client.on_log=on_log
client.on_message=on_message


print("connecting to broker ",broker_address+" :"+str(port))
client.connect(broker_address,port,60)

client.loop_start()



print("Publishing message to topic ",topic)
client.publish(topic, "python mqqt message")
result = mqtt1 + "changes"
print("recieved Message in Variable:",result)

time.sleep(4)
client.loop_stop() 
client.disconnect()
```

i would like to get the whole message object and work with that data in my script.

I see my msg.payload in the console with print in on_message.
but i cant use it, for instance, in the variable result.

I tried with a global variable, with a return from the on_message function. but nothing works.

I think I don't understand which parameters I should give the on_message function to get my returned value (later the whole msg object)

perhaps somebody can help me to understand.

---

here is my console output:

- =========== RESTART: C:\Users\user\Python\pyproj\project1\mqtt.py ==========
- creating new instance  Pythonscript
- connecting to broker  ip :1883
- Publishing message to topic  my topic
- recieved Message in Variable: changes
- message recieved: 73
- message in mqtt1: 73
- message recieved: 91
- message in mqtt1: 91
- message recieved: 57
- message in mqtt1: 57
- message recieved: 50
- message in mqtt1: 50
- message recieved: 50
- message in mqtt1: 50
- Disconnected result code 0

But I cant get the value in an variable out of the on_message function...

Answer (score 0):

You need to remember that the `on_message()` function is not called by any of your code, it is called by the MQTT client's network loop as it processes incoming packets from the network.

The `return` at the end of `on_message()` will not do anything useful as there is nowhere to return anything to.

Your next problem is that you have to remember that MQTT is asynchronous, so trying to read the value of `mqtt1` immediate after the call to `client.publish()` will just not work. Your code will try to read the value immediately, but you have no way of knowing how long it will take for a message to be delivered as a possible response from any client that is subscribed.

Remember that you should not think of MQTT as something like HTTP, it is **not** a request response synchronous model. While MQTTv5 added the concept of response topics in the headers, it did not change the fact that a response message is totally separate the request message and may arrive, arrive late, never arrive or arrive multiple times from multiple other clients.

You need to spend some time learning about asynchronous systems and look at how you maintain state under those circumstances (e.g. a state machine model)

Comment: i understand that. the mqtt1 variable and the return m_decode where tries to get the recieved object into an useable variable.
I get the message from the broker but i cant use it in my code. thats the only problem...

Comment: I'm saying you need to change your whole approach, you can not just publish and expect to use a returned result as you have, processing of the reply **NEEDS** to be triggered from the `on_message` callback.

Comment: mhmmm i think i understand what you are telling me. But my publish and the subscribtion arent related to another. 
if there where related i had to check the reply in on_message to bring the data in relation again. did i understand that correctly? 
but after that i would like to use the data in other functions. 

in the last time only worked with node Red and i am new in python.

Comment: Then `mqtt1` either needs to be set to sensible defaults or tested to see if it's been set yet where ever you try and use it. But there isn't enough information in the question to say anything else

Comment: so for an example, with independent publish/subscribe :
if i would like to see the value of an recieved mqqt message in a label i have to put that into the `on_message` function ? there is no way to do that elsewhere ?

Comment: If you want to update the label every time the message is received, basically yes. It can be in another function, but that will need to be triggered by `on_message` as that is the only notification you will get the message was received and the value changed.

Comment: ahh ok. so i would need a function call for the label function in `on_message`.
But how do i get the payload to that label function ? With transfer parameters ?
would you take a view on my complete code (with a gui) to tell me what i could do better ? may be i am doing things wrong without knowing it...

Comment: I'm not going to answer any more, as I said there is not enough information in the question to say any more.